# Ajaxing refresh to a div once added an "Item"

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery

I've gotten my view to successfully add my item to my cart. However, I just want it to ajax refresh (of sorts) the '#cart' div, while still on the original page. In other words, the item is added to into the cart, but only shown if I manually refresh. I just want it to look smooth and ajax-y.

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def add(request, profile):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed('POST')
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(slug=slugify(request.POST['itemname']))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        item = Item(name=request.POST['itemname'])
        item.save()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    profile.items.add(item)
    response = simplejson.dumps(
                {"status": "Successfully added."}
            )
    return HttpResponse (response, mimetype='application/json')
```

Template:

```
<form id="addItemForm" class="form-style" method="POST" action="/item/add/{{ profile }}/"> 
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input id="item-input" class="input-text inline required" name="itemname" type="text" />
     <button class="blue" type="submit" id="additem">
         Add Item 
     </button> 
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('#addItemForm').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var form = $("#additem").attr("action");
     var post_data = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     $('.item-selection').html(data);

      result = $.ajax({
           url: form,
           data: post_data, 
           type: "POST",

            success: function(data) {
                  //alert("Successfully added");
          console.log()
          $("#item-selection").replaceWith($('#item-selection', $(html)));
                  //{[( THIS IS WHERE I'D LIKE IT TO REFRESH)]}
             }, 
             error: function(data) {
                  // return the user to the add item form
           $('#addItemForm').html(data);
         }
    });
});
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

( I apologize for the formatting )
I'm an ajax beginner. It's clearly something wrong with my script. I just don't know where to go from here.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i cant see in your code what you mean. but this should reload the #cart element.. alhtough there is probably a better way to do it without downloading the entire page again just for the content on one element

```
$('#cart').load('ajax/test.html #cart');
```

Comment: This doesn't want to work either... Looking at the console, I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.. But I'm sure that's not all thats wrong with it.

Comment: in one place u are using it as a class `.item-selection`  in another, you are calling it by id `#item-selection`  or those the same element?

Comment: removed ` $('.item-selection').html(data);` all together. Still works, just doesn't successfully refresh the div.

Comment: make sure the url you use in the `load()` is the url to your cart page, not the url your updating the cart.eg :`index.php?show=cart`  or however u access the cart